# Минимальная обвязка ESP12-F

Tags: esp8266

Хочу сделать свои платы на основе ESP12-F но не могу найти минимальную обвязку. Если у кого то есть отправьте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В даташите все нашлось, к счастью:

[image: Схема]

Comment: Действительно в даташите от LCSC есть спасибо!